# Tracd Realm

Tags: python, project-management, wiki, trac

I am trying to setup tracd for the project I am currently working on.
After creating a password file with the python script given in the [site](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone) I am trying to start the server with authentication on. But it throws up warning saying No users found in the realm. What actually is a realm - I tried using trac as the value and also tried leaving it empty. I am using Windows XP.  I am using Tracd Standalone server.

The Command Line sent was: tracd --port 8000 --auth=My_Test_Project,D:\My_Test_Project\Documents\Trac\digest.txt,Trac  D:\My_Test_Project\Documents\Trac

The Warning message was - 'Warning: found no users in realm: trac'

Thanks...

Comment: You ought to provide _the error message_ instead of a description of the error message...

Comment: Added the error message with the question.

Comment: Even though the question is only somewhat programming related: you should also post the complete command line you're using to launch tracd.

Comment: Added the command line that was used!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing the above said command line with the one bellow helps.

tracd --port 8000 --auth=Trac,D:\My_Test_Project\Documents\Trac\digest.txt,Trac D:\My_Test_Project\Documents\Trac

The string after --auth= should be the environment name and not the project name.

Answer (score 5):

Check your password digest file.  Looking at mine it appears that the output is stored as a line with three fields in this format: `username:realm:passwordhash`.  If your getting that warning then it could be a mismatch between the realm field in the digest file and the realm that you're passing in when launching tracd.

---

Looking in the python generator script there are three options:

- -u for user
- -p for password
- -r for realm

When I generate my digest file using this command line (assuming you named it trac-digest.py):

```
python trac-digest.py -u user -p pass >> digest.txt
```

it generates this line in my digest.txt:

```
user:trac:1d395970d2a9a075d0536a4d6e4d0679
```

So looks like the default realm is *trac* and launching tracd with the --auth option specified like the documentation says always gives me that warning 'Warning: found no users in realm: *realm*'
But when I generate my digest file using the -r parameter:

```
python trac-digest.py -u user -p pass -r realm >> digest.txt
```

it generates this line in my digest.txt:

```
user:realm:1d395970d2a9a075d0536a4d6e4d0679
```

And I no longer get that warning when I specify the realm that I passed to trac-digest.py.

Answer (score 1):

The text referred to says that you must specify the realm name as "trac", not "**T**rac", but I have no chance of testing whether that makes any difference, sorry.